# Date Conversion CST in angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, ionic2

I am getting time like "DOB": "/Date(862588800000+0800)/" from json API but I have to convert it into something like Date Format : 04/28/2017 10:20:05 (MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:sss) . Need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by parsing the value to a Date object, then formatting the output.

The first number part appears to be a time value that is milliseconds since the epoch (1970-01-01), followed by a timezone offset in HHMM. Time values before the epoch are negative, so a regular expression to get the parts might be:

```
/[+-]?\d+/g
```

which should match both the time value and the offset.

The time value can adjusted by the offset then used to create a Date (the value passed to the Date constructor needs to be a number, or it will be parsed as if it's a string):

```js
function parseDate(s) {
  // Get the parts
  var b = s.match(/[+-]?\d+/g);

  // If appears invalid, return invalid Date      
  if (!b || b.length != 2) return new Date(NaN);
  
  // Get sign of offset
  var sign = +b[1] < 0? -1 : 1;

  // Convert offset to milliseconds
  // Multiplication converts the strings to numbers so + adds
  var offset = sign * b[1].substr(1,2)*3.6e6 + b[1].substr(3,2)*6e4;

  // Adjust time value by offset, create a Date and return it
  // Subtraction also converts the time value to a number
  return new Date(b[0] - offset);
}

var s = '/Date(862588800000+0800)/';

console.log(parseDate(s));
```

The validation could also use a regular expression like:

```
/\(-?\d+[+-]\d{4}\)/.test(s)
```

As for formatting the Date, there are many questions about that already, see [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: awesome man ..  Thanks a lot . can you do some more for me to change it in 02 May 1997 . currently i am getting Fri May 02 1997 13:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

Comment: I did it . Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

## Here i imagine you are displaying your date inside  or  element. Angular having a concept of datepipes. For a given date it will convert to the format

For Eg:

{{document.lastUpdateDateTime | date:"MM/dd/yyyy h:mma" :'CST6CDT'}}

it will represent the date in *MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:SS*S format.

please go through this one.

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

[https://www.prokerala.com/travel/timezones/CST6CDT][2]

### In case you want to represent date in your own way. You can write like this.

```
<td>{{document.lastUpdateDateTime | date:"MM/dd/yyyy h:mma" :'CST6CDT'}}</td>
```

### you can customize this function in your own way to get your desired results

write a function inside a controller.
.

```
    $scope.getCSTDateTime= function(lastUpdateDateTime) {
     var currentDate = new Date(lastUpdateDateTime);
     console.log("Current Date is :" + currentDate);


     var h = currentDate .getHours();
     var mm = currentDate .getMinutes();
     var SSS = currentDate .getSeconds();

      //date:"MM/dd/yyyy h:mma" :'CDT'
      var month = currentDate .getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
      var day = currentDate .getUTCDate();
      var year = currentDate .getUTCFullYear();
      return     month + "/" + day + "/" +year +" "+h+":"+mm+":"+SSS;
};
```